# Paste string to ActiveCell from memory

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check first, If ActiveCell is empty then just:

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:B1").Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Then if ActiveCell is not empty I would like to:

1. Store activecell value in memory
2. Copy range with certain formatting from another Sheet
3. Paste range from another Sheet to AciveCell with Offset
4. Paste value from memory to ActiveCell

I can't figure out how to paste value from memory to ActiveCell. Any hint?

Here is my current code:

```
Sub TimescheduleIndent1()

    Dim KeepMeInMemory As String

    If Intersect(ActiveCell, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Timeschedule").Range("B8:B90")) Is Nothing Then

    Else

        If ActiveCell = "" Then

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:B1").Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Else

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ActiveCell = KeepMeInMemory

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:B1").Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' Here should come value from memory *KeepMeInMemory*
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

The whole code is applicable only for range `B8:B90`. If ActiveCell is not in range then do nothing.

Comment: So why don't you use a variant variable? You seem to be using variables so it doesn't look like this should be difficult to you. Or is this too simplisticly thought of me? > `Dim KeepMeInMemory` > `KeepMeInMemory = ActiveCell.Value`

Comment: `ActiveCell = KeepMeInMemory` -  that's loading the value of `KeepMeInMemory` into the active cell. Are you sure that's what you had in mind for that part of your code??

Comment: Damn, thank you guys! I just got stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of how you are trying to store the ActiveCell value here

```
ActiveCell = KeepMeInMemory
```

What this is trying to do is set the `ActiveCell` to the variable `KeepMeInMemory`, which is empty as you haven't assigned anything to it. Instead what you need to do is.

```
KeepMeInMemory = ActiveCell.value
```

Then if you actually want to set a cell value to that variable you need to assign it like this.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).value = KeepMeInMemory
```

I think this is what you are trying to do.